# String to bytes to string

Tags: java, string, arrays, byte

**The question is in comments in the code**, I thought that'd be an easier way to ask...

Easy question, but I can't seem to find an answer. I want to convert a String to it's `byte[]` (easy, `String.getBytes()`). Then I want to convert a String of bytes (`101011010101001` for example) to a byte[] and get the String value of that (that's easy too: `new String(byte[])`)

Here's what I've got so far:

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
String string = scan.nextLine();
String byteString = "";
for (byte b : string.getBytes()) {
  byteString += b;
}
System.out.println(byteString);

//This isn't exactly how it works, these two parts in separate methods, but you get the idea...

String byteString = scan.nextLine();
byte[] bytes = byteString.literalToBytes() //<== or something like that...
//The line above is pretty much all I need...
String string = new String(bytes);
System.out.println(string);
```

Comment: Check this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2057387/converting-a-set-of-strings-to-a-byte-array

Comment: I'll edit it so it's a little more clear, but if you see in the code I have commments

Comment: First of all I would suggest you to use a StringBUilder for the variable byteString and then convert it back to string after the loop. Little Optimization :)

Comment: @StepTNT, that led me to the right answer. If you want to formalize the answer I'll accept it. Thanks.

Comment: @dharam, duly noted and fixed. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: I see that you added your own solution, you can accept that one :)

Comment: @StepTNT I tried to give you as much credit as I could. If you'd like I can remove mine and you can add one so you get the credit. Either way, thanks a lot.

Comment: There's no need for that. Just accept yours, I just gave you a link, no answer at all :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, because the [commenter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1094430/steptnt) who [pointed me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10722003/string-to-bytes-to-string/10722103#comment13925545_10722003) to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2057387/converting-a-set-of-strings-to-a-byte-array) (which lead me to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2057513/971592)) isn't going to answer, I'll just post the solution here:

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
String pass = scan.nextLine();
StringBuilder byteString = new StringBuilder();
for (byte b : pass.getBytes()) {
  b = (byte) (b);
  byteString.append(b).append(","); //appending that comma is what does the trick.
}
System.out.println(byteString);
//
String[] split = byteString.toString().split(","); //splitting by that comma is what does the trick... too...
byte[] bytes = new byte[split.length];
for (int i = 0; i < split.length; i++) {
  bytes[i] = (byte) (Byte.valueOf(split[i]).byteValue());
}
System.out.println(new String(bytes));
```

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**

Please see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2057489/518587) answer for a solution.

With this you can:

```
String string = scan.nextLine();
String convertByte = convertByte(string.getBytes());
System.out.println(convertByte);
String byteString = scan.nextLine();
System.out.println(new String(convertStr(byteString)));
```

Comment: Sorry, that wont work for the cases I'm working with. I just tried it with the string `kent` which gave me a byte string of: `107101110116`. Giving your answer that byte string throws a NumberFormatException on `Integer.toBinaryString(Integer.parseInt(string));` Which makes sense. But one of the commenters on my question gave me a link to a good answer. If they doesn't post the comment in an answer I'll just post my answer. Thanks for the help though.

Comment: I dont just want to copy the solution, but I added a link to it.

Answer (score 1):

This won't work. The problem is that when you convert your bytes to a string you are going to get a string like

2532611134

So analyzing this string, is the first byte 2, or 25, or 253?

The only way to make this work would be to use a DecimalFormat and make sure every byte is 3 characters long in your string

Comment: Another option would be to convert to hexadecimal (2 digits 0-F per byte) or use a separator between the bytes, e.g. space character.

Answer (score 0):

I guess what you want is this

```
// to get back the string from byte array
StringBuilder byteString = new StringBuilder();
for (byte b : string.getBytes()) {
    byteString.append((char)b);
}
   System.out.println(byteString.toString());
// to get the binary representation from string
StringBuilder byteString = new StringBuilder();
    for (byte b : string.getBytes()) {
        System.out.print(Integer.toBinaryString((int)b));
    }
        System.out.println(byteString.toString());
```

Comment: That is the same as new String(string.getBytes()). It does not print the binary representation of the String.

Comment: @morja, that's right. I need it to print the byte representation and then convert the string version of the byte representation back to the string it represented originally. Someone answered the question in a comment though. I'm just waiting for a formalized answer so I can accept it.

Comment: Awesome, now to answer the *original* question. How to convert that byte string back to the original string it represents? I already got the answer, but feel free to update your answer if you like.

Comment: You have to substring the byteString into pieces of length 8 and individually parse each of them into int and then typecaste into a byte and then typecaset to char.