# How to convert string to byte[] with same content

Tags: java, string

I want to convert string to byte[] with same content. Example
I have:

```
String str = "abc";
byte[] bytes;
//I want to convert "str" to "bytes" that they have same content:
(code here)
//after, print bytes -> "abc".
```

Comment: I try to using getBytes, but it's wrong.

Answer (score 4):

With a little effort, you'd reach this.

So what we do is use the `getBytes` method

```
byte[] convertToBytes= stuff.getBytes("UTF-8");
String newString = new String(convertToBytes, "UTF-8");
```

[source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7401941/how-to-convert-string-into-byte-and-back)

[Converting a set of strings to a byte[] array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2057387/converting-a-set-of-strings-to-a-byte-array?rq=1)

[Also study up on the String API page](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html)

Comment: I want to they have same content, When using getBytes(), it's value is different

Answer (score 1):

```
        String str = "abc";
        byte bytes[] = str.getBytes(); // Get the byte array
         for (byte b : bytes) {
            System.out.println("Byte is "+b);  //Iterate and print
        }
        str = new String(bytes);   // Create String from byte array
        System.out.println("String is "+str);
```

Comment: I want to they have same content, When using getBytes(), it's value is different

Comment: @user3150907 which value is different ??

Comment: "str" and "bytes". I want to value of variable "str" and "bytes" are same, so I don't use getBytes() method.

Comment: dear str is string and bytes is array of byte of that string.How can you make both same.